# Running adb commands in silent mode (without output)

Tags: python, adb

Is it possible to run adb commands in silent mode or something like that? For instance, whenever I pull a file, it returns `1 file pulled, 0 skipped. 11.3 MB/s (705431 bytes in 0.059s)`, which may be annoying if your script is doing it very often.

I'm not sure if it matter, but I'm using VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if your using Linux adb pull source dest > /dev/null. For windows am not sure it should be $null or something